# Changes in Type Script file is not updating in .js file, Ionic 2 Visual Studio

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, ionic2

I am just started learning Ionic 2 framework and using Visual Studio 2015 as IDE. I am working on their starter project **ionic 2-ts-sidemenu**.

The problem is whatever changes that i making on .ts file no effect at all. Like adding new page, changing page title in side detail etc.

Additional Info:-

1) If i made any change in app.bundle.js manually then things are working good.

2) any changes in .html file are working too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find a solution we have to build project first for that Follow these steps-

1) Using Visual Studio 2015, do right click in the gulpfile.js and open the Task Runner Explorer
OR use this shortcut Ctrl + ALT + Backspace.

[image: First Step]

2) Once there, you can bind the clean and build to run them before building the project

[image]

And that's all. Whenever you try now to build or run your app using Visual Studio 2015, this two tasks will be executed before building the project and the build directory inside www folder will be updated. Thanks